# Can this post support be used for a fence (especially for posts that support a gate)

Tags: post, support

Can this post support be used for a fence (especially for posts that support a gate) ( http://www.homedepot.ca/product/bolt-down-in-khaki-4-in-x-4-in/971849)
[image]

Comment: I'd be leery about using it for a gate.  There's a lot of horizontal and torquing forces that would cause it to loosen up.  What would it be going into?

Comment: The post support? It will be bolted down in concrete ..

Comment: (I seem to say this a lot, but) put a "gate wheel" on the gate, and it'll be fine as a hinge post. Unlikely to work otherwise, imho.

Comment: I have to open the gate outside toward a sloped driveway. The wheel will lose contact with the ground in the first 3-4 inches of its swing